# Web Text Editor Like Word which work with pages, template header and footer

Tags: text-editor, web, templating

I'm searching for a web text editor like Word where we can write content but I have only 1 obligation, I want to be able to edit the header and footer of EACH PAGE.

I tried CKEditor but I didn't find a solution to edit header and footer. I found one solution: it's to add HTML content at the bottom and the end of my content but this works only if I have 1 page.

[image]

Here I want to be able to change "29/05/2019 Do you known a web text editor ? - Software Recommandations Stack Exchange" 
and "https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask" on each page.

Comment: 'web text editor' is not a thing.  Do you need a text editor that works on the web?  Or an editor for text that will appear on the web?  Also Word is a word processor, not a text editor.